# How to output only given chars?

Tags: bash

How can I crop unneeded chars, and only output what I need? For example:

input:

```
    ASDFQWER
```

output:

```
    DFQ
```

I mean in this case I need only the 3.-4.-5. chars of the string. How do I do that?

Comment: It may help future readers if you could edit/clarify your question to state whether you are working with shell variables or text I/O streams.  Given the answer you chose to accept, it seems you were looking for the former but that is not entirely clear from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
echo "${string:index:length}"
```

for your example

```
x="ASDFQWER"
echo "${x:2:3}"
```

Answer (score 3):

`cut` is the simplest program I know which is able to do that.
example:

```
echo ASDFQWER | cut -c3,4,5
```